# Linq and .Count big database

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I create asp mvc project which get data from big Mysql database ~ 500000.

I added datatables to my frontend with individual columns filters, where shows only 10 entries.

[image]

```
data = dc.books.OrderBy(x => x.id).Where(x =>
        (market_id == 0 || x.market_id == market_id)
        && (name == null || x.name != null && (x.name.Contains(name)))
        && (author == null || x.author != null && (x.author.Contains(author)))
    ).Skip(param.Start).Take(10).ToList();
```

Work fast and good.

When I try add count after filters for pangination. Not work server Mysql Timeout error or work very slowly

```
count = db.books.Count(x =>
                    (market_id == 0 || x.market_id != 0 && x.market_id == market_id)
                    && (name == null || x.name != null && (x.name.StartsWith(name)))
```

Why count not work or so slowly?

All code my conttoller [here](https://pastebin.com/uAZyJs2a)

Comment: Sql Server tends to be very fast with counts (also with predicates). It's probably deeply ingrained in the database engine whether counts are fast or not. I don't know about MySql, but I think you're missing some vital index(es).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off doing this:

```
var query = db.books.AsQueryable();

if (market_id!=0)
  query = query.Where(x=>x.market_id==market_id);

if (name!=null)
  query = query.Where(x=>x.name.StartsWith(name));

count = query.Count();
data = query
  .OrderBy(x=>x.id)
  .Skip(param.Start)
  .Take(10)
  .ToList();
```

Not all LINQ providers are very good an optimizing away the filters, and will pass them on to the database.  Many databases will generate a terrible query plan for these types of queries, and generate the least worst-case query plan and re-use it for all queries that look like that, which will miss the possibility of using indexes that it normally would if you use the code above.

In a lot of cases, you might also want to limit the count, so you would do this:

```
count = query.Take(1001).Count();
```

then if count == 1001 then use the message "of more than 1000 results."

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to how databases work and what kind of SQL gets generated in the end. StartsWith gets translated to a wildcard search, which can be slower than simpler queries. You can try putting in indexes which will help the specific queries you're trying to optimize, and you can look at the generated SQL to check that it's as good as you'd expect (sometimes it can generate weird SQL but this looks like a simple enough query so I wouldn't worry too much about that yet). You might also want to check if there's any difference in the generated SQL if you add parentheses to separate the parts of the OR expressions, like `name == null || (x.name != null && (x.name.StartsWith(name)))`